# How can I rename a field heading in detail section of Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Is there a way to rename or use an alias for field headings in the detail section of a Crystal Report so that I can make it more meaningful to the reader.  An example, my field heading is 'PrtCnNote_3_Actual_Notes' and I would like to create an alias of 'Synopsis'.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Double click on the field heading and give the name you need.